# Application.Match very slow, copy and paste also used?

Tags: excel, vba, match, copy-paste, transpose

Hi all I am using the script below to check a number of columns against column A, However it is extremely slow and I was wondering if anyone knows of a quicker method.

In here I have a range of cells on different sheets being compared, once the comparison is made a check mark is made in the adjacent column and it is copied and pasted into a final sheet (possibly another slowing process) I cant think of a way to transpose without copying and pasting?

```
Sub CompareAndMove()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, k As Long, kL As Long, iL As Long, var As Variant, y As Workbook, lRows As Long

    lRows = Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    iL = Sheets("COMPARE").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 3 To 4
        For i = 2 To iL
            Set rng1 = Sheets("COMPARE").Range("A" & i)
            Set rng2 = Sheets("COMPARE").Columns(j)

            var = Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 1)

            If Not IsError(Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 0)) Then bln = True
                If bln = True Then
                    rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    rng1.Copy
                    rng1.Offset(0, 1).Font.Name = "Wingdings"
                    rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value = ChrW(&HFC)
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        Sheets("COMPARE").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lRows, "B")).Copy
        Sheets("COMPAREFINAL").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next j

    kL = Sheets("COMPARE").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lRows = Sheets("COMPAREOBD").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 3 To 4
        For k = 2 To kL
            Set rng1 = Sheets("COMPAREOBD").Range("A" & i)
            Set rng2 = Sheets("COMPAREOBD").Columns(j)

            var = Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 1)

            If Not IsError(Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 0)) Then bln = True
                If bln = True Then
                        rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        rng1.Copy
                        rng1.Offset(0, 1).Font.Name = "Wingdings"
                        rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value = ChrW(&HFC)
                End If
            End If
        Next k

        Set rng1 = Nothing
        Set rng2 = Nothing

        Sheets("COMPAREOBD").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lRows, "B")).Copy
        Sheets("COMPAREFINALOBD").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

the main slow down here i see is that you are checking one cell at a time with the `MATCH` formula, if your "iL" is more than in double digits it will be in fact very slow. Is the alternative possible where you just populate a column next to your full range with the `MATCH` formula and work off that?

Comment: No this macro is part of a larger set of instructions, therefore every time it runs there will be new data to compare against, I can not get around matching them one by one.

I can deal with how slow it is I guess but one problem I have run into now is I can not seem to copy column B (only cells with data) and paste into new sheet?

Comment: 1. but you are already using an extra column to put the mark on, but rather than doing one by one line why not to select whole range you are comparing with an offset of one column, populating with formula which would place your mark where it is not error?  2. does copying gives an error or you just want to skip blanks? If you just want to omit blanks, you can just copy whole lot, filter on blanks and remove entire rows?

Comment: 1. I do not understand your solution? Can you explain further please, 2. I need the blanks in there I just wish to copy a range column B from row 1 to row iL. (where iL is the last used cell in column "A" kind of complicated to explain why)

Comment: after you set both ranges you can get away with just these two lines  `rng1.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(RC[-1]," & rng2.Parent.Name & "!" & rng2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",0)),"""",""Mark"")"`      `rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value`    it will populate the range in a next column to your lookup range with "Mark" if there is a match, then it will overwrite the formula with values.

Comment: Thanks, how about the issue with the copying and pasting? Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: to be honest i see no reason why it wouldn't copy and transpose the data you require... i just used a snippet of your code on a different file, it copies all used cells in column "B" and transfers transposing to another sheets, however you are using 4 different sheets(named somewhat similar and confusing) and without further knowledge i have no idea for your reasons. another suggestions is, run your code in debug until past the copy line and when code is stopped on next like have a look at what EXACTLY it copies.

Comment: I have done that, it seems to copy the first time absolutely fine, the second time it however brings up an error 1004.

Comment: on which line does it fail? if on pasting, check if it has in fact copied the range you assume it must have copied.

Comment: On the copy, I don't quite understand the issue, as the range seems fine to me and in fact the first time I ran the script it worked.

Comment: run it, and when it fails, go to debug and check what you lRows equal to. and also, what error does it throw?